# Do I need jack studs for a [remodel] closet header that is perpendicular to ceiling joists?

Tags: doors, framing, closet

Closets used to have full 8ft sliding doors.  Converting to bifolds that are 6'8'' tall.

So I need to put in a header and frame it out to standard size.

The ceiling joists run perpendicular to the closet doorway.

Can I nail the header to the joists and call it good (since the header will only be bearing the weight of itself and the doors)

Or should I put in jack studs to help transfer weight to the foundation?

Comment: If you are adding a header that is 1'4" below the existing header and jamb, how can you nail it to the joists?

Comment: there is no existing header.  These closet "doorways" go up to the ceiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd build a stub wall using construction screws (for better pullout strength), and I'd double the bottom plate. I'd then screw (not nail) to the joists through the top plate, and to the king studs through the ends. You wouldn't need to remove drywall on the ceiling if you use at least 3" screws.

This will carry drywall and trim just fine and will be laterally rigid enough for your purposes. Bifold doors don't normally hang on the header these days.

Note: If the ceiling drywall is mounted to something other than the ceiling joists, such as to sheet metal angles attached to the wall plates, this is to deal with seasonal truss lift. In that case you shouldn't hang your header from the ceiling joists as it'll possibly move on a seasonal basis, tearing up the drywall with it. You'd want to rest it on the wall using a conventional trimmer setup, and it'll need to be robust enough to span the opening without sagging.

Comment: thank you.  the hardware i got does attach to the header.  I'll use screws for most of it.  thanks again

Comment: The hardware attaches to the header, but the door probably doesn't hang from it. It's merely a location guide.

Comment: Do you have a truss roof and are the ceiling joists the bottom chords of the trusses? If so, you need an opinion on how to treat this  from one of the expert framers on this site.

Comment: That's a good point, Jim, and one I hadn't considered. Answer updated.

Comment: I think I have a truss roof?  But the ceiling drywall is screwed directly into the joists / bottom chords.  I live in southern cali so I don't know if truss uplift is a major issue.  here are a couple pics (you can see the blocking along the closet doorway in the second pic):  http://imgur.com/a/U8E5L

Comment: If there was no header in the larger opening before then why would you need one now.

Comment: Because there was nothing to support. We're talking about adding a short wall, which will in turn support a door (to more or less extent).